# Hot o use Bitmap Index in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question conerning Bitmap Index on my table. Let's say I have the following table:

```
+----------------------+
| ID CITY COUNTY STATE |
+----------------------+
| 1 AUSTIN USA TEXAS   |
| 2 NYC USA NY         |
+----------------------+
```

And I would like to create bitmap index on `STATE` column.

I will create it using the following:

```
CREATE BITMAP INDEX Ind_STATE ON TableName(STATE);
```

Now, the question is: how can I use this bitmap index? Or this bitmap index will be used by system by default?

Comment: In general, the Oracle optimizer decide how to run the query, including which indexes to use.   You can force such use with a hint, if you like.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I guess that makes an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Although this is not your immediate question - you should use caution when creating a bitmap index, If your `state` column includes a large variety of columns, a bitmap index would not be an efficient choice to improve query performance. This type of index is most efficient to columns with very low cardinality, such as sex (which can only be male/female, traditionally). If the optimizer won't choose to use it without a hint, it might be because the index is not improving performance.